# `<main>': uninitialized constant Rabbit (NameError)

Tags: ruby, class

I have two files rabbit.rb and main01.rb in a same directory and when I run main01.rb, I get this error message 
`': uninitialized constant Rabbit (NameError)
what did I do wrong? Thanks for your help.

rabbit.rb

```
class Rabbit
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :color, :length_of_ears

  def initialize(name: "usachan", color: :white, length_of_ears: 10)
    @name = name
    @color = color
    @length_of_ears = length_of_ears
  end

  def jump
    puts "pyon! pyon!"
  end

  def pound_steamed_rice_into_rice_cake
    puts "pettan! pettan!"
  end

  def say_name
    puts "Hello, I'm #{name}!"
  end
end
```

main01.rb

```
require_relative "rabbit"

rabbits = []

rabbits.push(Rabbit.new)
rabbits.push(Rabbit.new(name: "pyonkichi"))
rabbits.push(Rabbit.new(name: "inaba", color: :brown, length_of_ears: 7))

rabbits.each do |rabbit|
  puts rabbit.name
  puts rabbit.color
  puts rabbit.length_of_ears
  rabbit.say_name
  puts ""
end

rabbit[0].name = "wooser"
puts rabbit[0].name
```

Comment: I don't know how you got your error msg. the last two lines of your codes have typo. Change the `rabbit[0]` to `rabbits[0]`. What the ruby version you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `require "./rabbit"` instead of `require_relative "rabbit"`

You are also referring to the array with the wrong variable name at the end of `main01.rb`. Try:

```
rabbits[0].name = "wooser"
puts rabbits[0].name
```

Comment: That's true, but the error was "uninitialized constant Rabbit", not "uninitialized variable rabbit".

Comment: @Adrian after fixing the typo, the code will not get the `uninitialized constant Rabbit` error..

Comment: Yes, but the code doesn't get that error even if the typo is there.

Comment: I fixed the typo but I get still same error: `<main>': uninitialized constant Rabbit (NameError)

Comment: @user2983011 Try changing `require_relative "rabbit"` to `require_relative "rabbit.rb"` maybe? Also make sure to save the file when you edit it :) Your error shouldn't be happening

Comment: What is your ruby version? Type `ruby --version` to find out

Comment: I just found out that I had 2 rabbit.rb file in two different locations and I kept saving the one above in the wrong location://  It's finally working.  Thanks everybody for such a quick response!